# 'function' object has no attribute 'get_extra_actions' on new endpoint

Tags: python, django

I am attempting to set up a new endpoint in my Django project:

```
router.register(
    r"v1/alert-summary/(?P<alert_id>[^/]+)/page/(?P<page>[^/]+)", alerts_views_v1.alert_summary, basename="Alerts"
)
```

`Alerts` is my model, and the method `alert_summary` is in the `alerts.views.py` file **BUT IS NOT IN THE `AlertViewSet` class**.

```
@api_view(["GET"])
def alert_summary(request):
    data = "hello world"
    return Response(data=data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

However, when I test this endpoint I keep getting this error:

```
'function' object has no attribute 'get_extra_actions'
```

Google searches and StackOverflow scrolling have proven fruitless, I have tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51648513/6187682) with no success, and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56924196/6187682) doesn't apply as the method isn't inside the ViewSet class.

What should I do?

Comment: The second one *does* apply (or rather, my accepted answer to that question does). Indeed, the method is not in a ViewSet class. But routers are for ViewSets only. You should not be using a router here.

Comment: @DanielRoseman should I use `url(PREFIX + r""v1/alert-summary/(?P<alert_id>[^/]+)/page/(?P<page>[^/]+)", alerts_views_v1.alert_summary)` instead? or something like it?

Comment: Yes, but better to actually put it in the viewset class as an [extra action](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing).