# Django rest framework error object X has no attribute 'get_extra_actions'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am wanting to add some search functionality to my API and I followed [this simple guide](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/?q=get_extra_actions#searchfilter) but I'm still getting the error

> type object 'ClientViewSet' has no attribute 'get_extra_actions'

---

### My setup

**Versions**

- Django: 2.2.5
- Django Rest Framework: 3.11.0
- Python: 3.8.2

models.py

```
class Client(models.Model):
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

urls.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'clients', ClientViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
]
```

serializers.py

```
class ClientSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
class ClientViewSet(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Client.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ClientSerializer
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter]
    search_fields = ['phone']
```

Comment: Yes, it's a `CharField`

Answer (score 1):

"You've called it a viewset, but that doesn't make it one; you inherit from APIView which is a standalone generic view, not a viewset.

A viewset needs to inherit from viewsets.ViewSet."

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49721133/8932675

Answer (score 1):

To build off [the answer provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49721133/4373927), a `ViewSet` needs to inherit from a `ViewSet` and the `ListAPIView` class does not inherit from `ViewSet`.

A way to get this to work, however, is to change the inherited class from `ListAPIView` to `ModelViewSet` like this:

```
class ClientViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Client.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ClientSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filter_fields = ['phone']
```